# How to hide multiple div by class and id in android webview

Tags: android, webview

There's a webpage I pull up with webview, however i'd like to hide the some div from div class name and divId. Is there a way to do this? The link is in the body,and I am able to hide first div Class from class second div calss and other div id is not hide.

```
  webView = new WebView(this);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("myUrl");
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            setContentView(webView);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('header-top')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('inchoo-socialconnect-login')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                            "document.getElementById('before-footer')[0].style.display='none';})()");
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                            "document.getElementById('footer')[0].style.display='none';})()");  
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call getElementById it returns a single element, and not an array like getElementsByClassName.

So try to remove the [0] from the Id calls and see if it helps.

eg.

`webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                            "document.getElementById('before-footer').style.display='none';})()");`